# Where does the $\pm$ in Einstein's energy-mass equivalence come from?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, mass-energy

Our professor taught us the equation $E= mc^2$ today, but he mentioned that this is only a part of a solution. He never taught us where it came from, but he did mention that this is only a partial expression- the real expression could also involve a negative sign. What does this even mean? And where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

The equation $E_{0}=mc^{2}$ indicating rest energy is indeed only the special case of more general formulas included in the [energy-momentum relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation):
$$E^{2}-(pc)^{2}=(mc^{2})^{2}$$
which includes the relativistic energy $E$ and momentum $p$:
$$E=\gamma mc^{2},\quad \vec{p}=\gamma m\vec{v}$$
where
$$\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-(v/c)^{2}}$$
from which $E_{0}=mc^{2}$ follows by setting $v=0$. Probably  your professor referred to the negative sign before $(pc)^{2}$.